# Nat from a non default gateway router

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, nat

I have a network with two different routers, like this:

```
Router1: WAN 1.1.1.1 LAN 10.0.0.1
Router2: WAN 2.2.2.2 LAN 10.0.0.2

PC1 (Windows 7) : LAN 10.0.0.11 GW: 10.0.0.2
PC2 (Windows 10): LAN 10.0.0.12 GW: 10.0.0.2
Other PCs: GW 10.0.0.1 (these have nothing to do with this question!)
```

I created two RDP NAT entries on Router1 that point to PC1 and PC2, respectively:

```
TCP 1.1.1.1:3391 -> 10.0.0.11:3389
TCP 1.1.1.1:3392 -> 10.0.0.12:3389
```

I didn't actually expect them to work, because packets from outside are x.x.x.x -> 1.1.1.1 while response packets become 2.2.2.2 -> x.x.x.x.

I found out that NAT to PC1 actually works, but I don't know why.

Now I'm trying to find a way to make it work on PC2, too.

Of course, if I set PC2 gateway to 10.0.0.1, NAT works perfectly.